# Program that can resize images to fit a defined maximum size

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, png

I'm looking for a program on Windows that can resize images, preferably in bulk, to fit a certain maximum size.

The images are in PNG format and are usually of a larger size than the limit of 3MB, so they need to be resized to fit that limit.

I've searched around a lot and also checked if Photoshop could do something similar, but without success. It's starting to get really annoying to manually have to resize image for image to make sure it doesn't exceed 3MB before uploading them.

Note: [ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917219/imagemagick-scale-jpeg-image-with-a-maximum-file-size#11920384) and IrfanView have this feature for JPG, but not for PNG.

Comment: i think that xnview exactly can this do.
[xnview](https://www.xnview.com/de/xnconvert/)

Answer (score 1):

The imagemagick tools can do this for you - read both answers provided on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917219/imagemagick-scale-jpeg-image-with-a-maximum-file-size

The first explains the quick way to do it. Note that you won't hit a precise max size, so give yourself some wiggle room.

The second explains a great way to go about doing it and maintaining max quality and making display easier later.

Comment: Still, I don't think it applies to PNG? Only JPEG?

Comment: @Chris should handle any image type that imagemagick can handle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [BatchPhoto](https://www.batchphoto.com/howto/resize/picture-size.html)?
It allows you to resize images in bulk and offers support for a wide range of image formats, including PNG. It works on both Windows and Mac.